# codeigniter4 countAllResults() empty string

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

in version 4.0.4 of codeigniter it does not give me an error but in version 4.1.3 it gives me an error

```
public function verificar($email, $cedula)
{
    $query = $this->db->table('veterinario AS v');
    $query->select('v.*');
    $query->where('v.email', $email);
    $query->where('v.cedula', $cedula);
    $querys = $query->get()->getResult();

    var_dump($querys);

    if (!empty($querys)) {
        if ($query->countAllResults() == 1) {
            echo 'encontrado';
        } else {
            echo 'noencontrado';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'noencontrado';
    }
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yWUt.png)

until the var_dump I check and if it brings me the data from the database but when entering the if it tells me that empty string
or it goes straight to the not found

Comment: try this `$query->countAllResults()` to this `$querys ->countAllResults()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the helper function `count`.

Replace the **countAllResults** with the **count** function like `$query->countAllResults() == 1` into `count($querys) == 1`.

It returns the number of rows returned by the query. You can use it like this:

```
public function verificar($email, $cedula)
{
    $query = $this->db->table('veterinario AS v');
    $query->select('v.*');
    $query->where('v.email', $email);
    $query->where('v.cedula', $cedula);
    $querys = $query->get()->getResult();

    var_dump($querys);

    if (!empty($querys)) {
        if (count($querys) == 1) {
            echo 'encontrado';
        } else {
            echo 'noencontrado';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'noencontrado';
    }
}
```